# Allow video download and secure downloaded video to restrict video access after validity expires

Tags: video, video-streaming, digital-signature

I am workng on a project where I want the user to download the video but restrict access in a way that the video stops working if it is copied to any other machine. Also the video stops working after a certain period of time.

Can some stackoverflow gurus help me point in a right direction?

Comment: can someone please add "video-security" as a tag? I believe this question fits the genre but with my low rep. StackOverflow wouldnt let me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Look into DRM. Digital rights management is used by copyright holders to control access and limit the use of digital content. Also, DRM tag is available so I am not sure if adding "video-security" tag would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

To make a video file stop working, you need to have it encrypted or otherwise incompatible with well known formats and encodings. This assumes that the file is downloaded and/or streamed being encrypted, you have custom offline and/or streaming player which supports this type of encoding and your player is responsible for checking copies and expiry time.

Comment: thanks RR. Can you please point me to any tutorial or blog where i can read more about it?